# Static Link for Armadillo

Tags: c++, static-libraries, armadillo

I have tried to statically link armadillo library to Visual Studio 2017 for C++ applying the steps below but to no avail. Platform is set for x64

1. C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories -> $(SolutionDir)Dependencies\include
2. Written `#include "armadillo"` (tried #include < armadillo > as well) in the source file.
3. Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies -> blas_win64_MT.lib; lapack_win64_MT.lib
4. Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories -> $(SolutionDir)Dependencies\lib_win64

Note:

> ***include*** is the name of a folder having ***armadillo*** and ***armadillo_bits*** folder in Step 1.
>
> ***lib_win64*** is the name of a folder having ***blas_win64_MT.lib*** and ***lapack_win64_MT.lib*** in Step 4

.

When I tried to compile, the following errors were encountered:

> c:\........\dependencies\include\armadillo_bits\arma_rng.hpp(444):
>   error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier', expected ';'
>
> c:\........\dependencies\include\armadillo_bits\arma_rng.hpp(524):
>   note: see reference to class template instantiation
>   '`arma::arma_rng::randn<std::complex<_Other>>`' being compiled

.

The code for arma_rng.hpp, directly from the armadillo library code.

```
template<typename T>
struct arma_rng::randn < std::complex<T> > 
  {
  inline
  operator std::complex<T> () const
    {
    T a, b; //************line 444***************

    arma_rng::randn<T>::dual_val(a, b);

    return std::complex<T>(a, b);
    }


  inline
  static
  void
  fill(std::complex<T>* mem, const uword N)
    {
    ...

  }; //************line 524***************
```

.

It is a code directly from armadillo example to test whether I have properly linked armadillo , no header file is implemented at the moment:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

// Armadillo documentation is available at:
// http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html

int
main(int argc, char** argv)
  {
  cout << "Armadillo version: " << arma_version::as_string() << endl;

  mat A(2,3);  // directly specify the matrix size (elements are uninitialised)

  cout << "A.n_rows: " << A.n_rows << endl;  // .n_rows and .n_cols are read only
  cout << "A.n_cols: " << A.n_cols << endl;

  A(1,2) = 456.0;  // directly access an element (indexing starts at 0)
  A.print("A:");

  A = 5.0;         // scalars are treated as a 1x1 matrix
  A.print("A:");

  A.set_size(4,5); // change the size (data is not preserved)

  A.fill(5.0);     // set all elements to a particular value
  A.print("A:");

  // endr indicates "end of row"
  A << 0.165300 << 0.454037 << 0.995795 << 0.124098 << 0.047084 << endr
    << 0.688782 << 0.036549 << 0.552848 << 0.937664 << 0.866401 << endr
    << 0.348740 << 0.479388 << 0.506228 << 0.145673 << 0.491547 << endr
    << 0.148678 << 0.682258 << 0.571154 << 0.874724 << 0.444632 << endr
    << 0.245726 << 0.595218 << 0.409327 << 0.367827 << 0.385736 << endr;

  A.print("A:");

  // determinant
  cout << "det(A): " << det(A) << endl;

  // inverse
  cout << "inv(A): " << endl << inv(A) << endl;

  // save matrix as a text file
  A.save("A.txt", raw_ascii);

  // load from file
  mat B;
  B.load("A.txt");

  // submatrices
  cout << "B( span(0,2), span(3,4) ):" << endl << B( span(0,2), span(3,4) ) << endl;

  cout << "B( 0,3, size(3,2) ):" << endl << B( 0,3, size(3,2) ) << endl;

  cout << "B.row(0): " << endl << B.row(0) << endl;

  cout << "B.col(1): " << endl << B.col(1) << endl;

  // transpose
  cout << "B.t(): " << endl << B.t() << endl;

  // maximum from each column (traverse along rows)
  cout << "max(B): " << endl << max(B) << endl;

  // maximum from each row (traverse along columns)
  cout << "max(B,1): " << endl << max(B,1) << endl;

  // maximum value in B
  cout << "max(max(B)) = " << max(max(B)) << endl;

  // sum of each column (traverse along rows)
  cout << "sum(B): " << endl << sum(B) << endl;

  // sum of each row (traverse along columns)
  cout << "sum(B,1) =" << endl << sum(B,1) << endl;

  // sum of all elements
  cout << "accu(B): " << accu(B) << endl;

  // trace = sum along diagonal
  cout << "trace(B): " << trace(B) << endl;

  // generate the identity matrix
  mat C = eye<mat>(4,4);

  // random matrix with values uniformly distributed in the [0,1] interval
  mat D = randu<mat>(4,4);
  D.print("D:");

  // row vectors are treated like a matrix with one row
  rowvec r;
  r << 0.59119 << 0.77321 << 0.60275 << 0.35887 << 0.51683;
  r.print("r:");

  // column vectors are treated like a matrix with one column
  vec q;
  q << 0.14333 << 0.59478 << 0.14481 << 0.58558 << 0.60809;
  q.print("q:");

  // convert matrix to vector; data in matrices is stored column-by-column
  vec v = vectorise(A);
  v.print("v:");

  // dot or inner product
  cout << "as_scalar(r*q): " << as_scalar(r*q) << endl;

  // outer product
  cout << "q*r: " << endl << q*r << endl;

  // multiply-and-accumulate operation (no temporary matrices are created)
  cout << "accu(A % B) = " << accu(A % B) << endl;

  // example of a compound operation
  B += 2.0 * A.t();
  B.print("B:");

  // imat specifies an integer matrix
  imat AA;
  imat BB;

  AA << 1 << 2 << 3 << endr << 4 << 5 << 6 << endr << 7 << 8 << 9;
  BB << 3 << 2 << 1 << endr << 6 << 5 << 4 << endr << 9 << 8 << 7;

  // comparison of matrices (element-wise); output of a relational operator is a umat
  umat ZZ = (AA >= BB);
  ZZ.print("ZZ:");

  // cubes ("3D matrices")
  cube Q( B.n_rows, B.n_cols, 2 );

  Q.slice(0) = B;
  Q.slice(1) = 2.0 * B;

  Q.print("Q:");

  // 2D field of matrices; 3D fields are also supported
  field<mat> F(4,3); 

  for(uword col=0; col < F.n_cols; ++col)
  for(uword row=0; row < F.n_rows; ++row)
    {
    F(row,col) = randu<mat>(2,3);  // each element in field<mat> is a matrix
    }

  F.print("F:");

  return 0;
  }
```

.

Comment: Those errors have nothing to do with linking. They happen during parsing of the code, long before linking is done. Is there a macro-define missing, or are you using a symbol declared in a header file wrongly? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you can show us, and it will be so much easier to help you.

Comment: Include a few lines from the header files around the errors in your post, say say about 5 lines above and below each.

Comment: I have added the code from armadillo which I was having trouble compiling. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: No header files have been used as this is the example from armadillo and I have included some of the codes from armadillo @RichardCritten

Answer (score 1):

Please change your VS2017 platform toolset to v140 instead of v141. Then compile, it must work.

Answer (score 1):

For others facing the same issues, using the `VC++ 2015.3 v140 toolset` worked for me to compile `OpenBLAS` and `armadillo` as static libraries.

These are the steps needed for Visual Studio 2017 (**VS2017**):

- install the `v140` toolset if needed:

  - modify the **VS2017** installation (i.e, details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/modify-visual-studio#modify-workloads))
  - check the **Desktop development `C++`** box
  - on the right side, under **Summary** click **Desktop development with C++**
  - at the bottom of the list check **VC++ 2015.3 v140 toolset for desktop (x86, x64)**
- next, you need to tell the compiler to use the `v140` instead of `v141`, therefore:

  - right click on the project name in **VS2017**
  - go to **Configuration Properties** → **General** → **Platform Toolset**
  - select **Visual Studio 2015 (v140)**

Now you should be able to `#include <armadillo>` and compile your code.

**Notes:**

- you still need to make sure that you set the proper include paths (i.e., if you installed `armadillo` via the **Nuget Package Manager** just following the steps indicated above will do the trick)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is a *BUG* caused by Visual Studio 2017,which related to the ***Conformance Mode*** has been recently enabled by default in Visual Studio.They try to fixed it(details [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/189476/cannot-compile-the-armadillo-library.html)).

A workaround solution worked in *VS2017* (V141,instead of install V140),is to ***Disabling Conformance Mode***.You can try like this way:

- Project properties -> C/C++ -> language -> Conformance Mode -> ***Disable***